# Copy constructor when declaring two objects

Tags: c++

Does declaring the following:

```
MyClass myFirstObject;    
MyClass mySecondObject = myFirstObject;
```

mean that the copy constructor is used for the second object even if no parameter is passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,A copy constructor is used to initialize an object with a differnt object of same type.
Situation where a copy constructor is called

```
MyClass A;
MyClass B(A);         //Explicit Copy constructor invoked
MyClass C = A;        //Implicit Copy constructor invoked
```

Comment: Addendum: The second line is an explicit copy and the third is an implicit copy.

Comment: @DonLarynx What if  `MyClass` has a custom copy constructor defined? In that case would 2nd and 3rd lines be calling an explicit copy constructor?

Comment: @RawN The only time an explicit constructor is called is when you don't use the equals sign, like so: `MyClass A = C` where `C` can be any type. Here the compiler chooses what constructor to use, and it would be `MyClass::MyClass(const TypeOfC&);` which is a conversion constructor. The compiler had to choose what type of constructor to use, hence implicit. If you say `MyClass A(C)`, the conversion constructor is still called, but you told the compiler to call it.

Comment: I see. Wasn't aware of that. I was under the impression that if you declared an explicit copy constructor then that's the one that's going to be called all the time. Your comment clarifies the issue.

Comment: If you declare `explicit MyClass::MyClass(const T&)`, then the line `MyClass A = otherType` where `otherType` is of type `T` is impossible since this is an implicit conversion.

Comment: Even i was'nt aware.Thanks for the explanation @DonLarynx

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check is by adding a `cout` statement in the copy constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&){

std::cout << "I am called!";

/*do stuff*/

}
```